# Why are the Mandalorian Supercomandos blaster bolts yellow?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels, mandalorian

In Clone Wars, the blasts from the weapons of the Galactic Republic were blue (extra ionization) to be more effective against the droids of the Confederation. In general, blaster bolts appear to be red. Since this is the case, why does Gar Saxon’s group of super commandos fire yellow ammunition?

Answer (score 2):

To put it simply, the color of your blaster bolt depends on the gas used as ammunition.

> Blaster bolts came in different colors. Red was the most common color,
> and was made from cheaper gas. This color was used by the Confederacy
> of Independent Systems, the Rebel Alliance, the Galactic Empire, and
> the First Order. Blue was used by the Galactic Republic, and the
> Resistance. This was an ionized type of blaster bolt that specialized
> in disabling machinery such as droids but was also effective against
> organic beings. Green was used by Naboo Security Forces, and the
> Umbarans, as well as the Starfighter Corps of the Galactic Empire.
> This was a more expensive and more powerful type of blaster gas.
> **Yellow was used by Mandalorians**. Purple was used by the Geonosian
> Starfighters, the Malevolence and most notably the Magna Guards.
> Purple was also used by the Techno Union octuptarra tri-droid variants
> on the planet Skako Minor. Orange was used by the Marksman-H training
> remote and training droids on Kamino as a low power and non-lethal
> type of blaster bolt. Cyan was a low-powered version of the blue
> blaster bolt that was used by clone cadets in their training sessions
> against training droids.
>
> Source : [Star Wars Wiki](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Blaster)

Comment: basically, there’s no reason, just it says so?